# How to query Algolia utilizing search string AND array of items to check against?

Tags: angular, ionic2, algolia

I have some search functionality inside of my Ionic 2 app that requires the ability to add filters to a search, in addition to the search string. I have the search string piece working, but I'm not sure how to pass in an array of values to check against a specific array in my Algolia indice.

Here is my function:

```
searchForUsers(filters?) {
    let options = {
      attributesToHighlight: ['display_name', 'instruments'],
      highlightPreTag: '<span class="highlighted">',
      highlightPostTag: '</span>',
      attributesToRetrieve: [
        "_geoloc",
        "display_name",
        "genres",
        "instruments",
        "objectID",
        "playing_level",
        "profile_photo",
      ],
    };

    // If there are any filters enabled?
    if(filters) {
      options['aroundLatLng'] = `${this.geoloc.lat},${this.geoloc.lng}`;
      options['aroundRadius'] = this._utilities.milesToMeters(this.distance);
    }

    this.usersIndex.search(this.searchTerm, options)
      .then((data) => {
        this.results = data.hits;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

If I wanted to add the following filters to my search, how could I go about doing this?

`["Blues", "Rock", "Alternative"]` // <-- These would check against `genres` in Algolia.
`["Guitar", "Drums", "Piano"]` // <-- These would check against `instruments` in Algolia.

^ These two arrays would be additional filters that would limit which results come back, like you see in thousands of different search components. Though I can't quite figure this out. Any idea?

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two ways to do this.

## Advanced Search

You can either, go into your Algolia admin panel and turn on `Advanced Syntax` and also set `Remove words if no results` to `allOptional` under the `Query Expansion` panel in the `ranking` settings page which will allow you to do a search query like below.

`"Blues" "Rock" "Alternative" "Guitar" "Drums" "Piano"`

This approach is good for broadly matching anything that matches the quoted search params but may not serve your needs. Personally I nearly always need more fine grain control.

## Facets

The second approach is to turn on faceting for those fields and then run a search query with a `filters` query like the following examples.

`genres: "Blues" OR genres: "Rock" OR genres: "Alternative"`

`instruments: "Guitar" OR instruments: "Drums" OR instruments: "Piano"`

This approach allows you to properly drill down into the results and combine search properties.

In your case here is an example.

```
let options = {
  filters: 'genres: "Blues" OR genres: "Rock" OR genres: "Alternative" AND Guitar" OR instruments: "Drums" OR instruments: "Piano"',
  attributesToHighlight: ['display_name', 'instruments'],
  highlightPreTag: '<span class="highlighted">',
  highlightPostTag: '</span>',
  attributesToRetrieve: [
    "_geoloc",
    "display_name",
    "genres",
    "instruments",
    "objectID",
    "playing_level",
    "profile_photo",
  ],
};
```

Comment: This was perfect and exactly what I needed. Thankyou

Comment: No problem. Happy that it's what you needed. Happy Coding! :)